# VB.Net Move an object[Error]

Tags: vb.net

i just start create a project with this(To The Topic)
an error is start in here(maybe)
First Button Code

```
Private Sub DeimosButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeimosButton2.Click
        State(i)
        DeimosButton3.Visible = False
        DeimosButton4.Visible = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer4_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
        DeimosButton2.Top = DeimosButton2.Top - 1
        If DeimosButton2.Location = New Point(22, 54) Then
            Timer4.Stop()
            DeimosButton2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub State(ByVal Ref As Integer)
        If Ref = 0 Then
            Timer4.Start()
            DeimosButton2.Enabled = False
            i = 1
        Else
            Timer5.Start()
            DeimosButton2.Enabled = False
            i = 0
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer5_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer5.Tick
        DeimosButton2.Top = DeimosButton2.Top + 1
        If DeimosButton2.Location = New Point(22, 85) Then
            Timer5.Stop()
            DeimosButton2.Enabled = True
            DeimosButton3.Visible = True
            DeimosButton4.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

This Second Button Code

```
Private Sub DeimosButton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeimosButton3.Click
    states(o)
    DeimosButton2.Visible = False
    DeimosButton4.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub Timer6_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer6.Tick
    DeimosButton3.Top = DeimosButton3.Top - 1
    If DeimosButton3.Location = New Point(22, 54) Then
        Timer6.Stop()
        DeimosButton3.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub states(ByVal Def As Integer)
    If Def = 0 Then
        Timer6.Start()
        DeimosButton3.Enabled = False
        o = 1
    Else
        Timer7.Start()
        DeimosButton3.Enabled = False
        o = 0
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Timer7_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer7.Tick
    DeimosButton3.Top = DeimosButton3.Top + 1
    If DeimosButton3.Location = New Point(22, 116) Then
        Timer7.Stop()
        DeimosButton3.Enabled = True
        DeimosButton2.Visible = True
        DeimosButton4.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is when i click the second button
but when i click the first button, is no matter.
Problem : The button is still moving to top, although it is has reach the position.
there is a solution for this ?

Comment: There are multiple logical mistakes in this program.  It won't work at all when Location.X isn't 22.  You want to stop when the Top property is too high or too low so only test Top, not Location.  Spend more time with the debugger.

Comment: But The First Code for button 1 is work

Comment: Oh i know, is not location but location.Y
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change

```
DeimosButton3.Location = New Point(22, 116)
```

to

```
DeimosButton3.Location.y = 116
```

This is valid to all
for all your code